# Как сделать метод, которй принимат в один параметр объект одного из двух типов?

Tags: c#

Есть класс с одним методом:

```
class A 
{
   public object Fill(HttpCLient / HttpWebRequest param)
   {
        //логика
   }
}
```

**Как сделать так, чтобы в параметр метода objectFill можно было передавать либо HttpCLient либо HttpWebRequest ?**

Я пытался делать через **T** но не получилось.

Спасибо

Comment: сделайте 2 метода, один с одним параметром, другой с другим

Comment: возможно, будет не вредно указать почему именно так и зачем вам это надо) так-то можно и [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264741(v=vs.120)) накостылить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите интерфейс, с которым будете работать в методе Fill и в двух классах реализуйте этот интерфейс, в одном с помощью HttpClient, во втором с помощью HttpWebRequest и передавайте в метод Fill экземпляры этих классов.

Пример с generic:

```
public void Fill<T>(T client)
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(HttpClient))
    {
        (client as HttpClient)?.GetAsync();
    }

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(HttpWebRequest))
    {
        (client as HttpWebRequest)?.GetResponseAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. а с помощью generic type одним методом можно это сделать?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Кстати, вместо `if (typeof(T) == typeof(HttpClient))` можно делать `if (client is HttpClient)` =)